# Dependencies on RequireJS main module

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Let's say I have a bundle `common/lib`, where I define RequireJS modules for jQuery and AngularJS.

Now let's suppose I have the following `config.js`:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'http://www.some-website.com/scripts/',
    paths: {
       'common/lib': 'bundles/common/lib',
    },
    shim: {
       'main': ['common/lib']
    }
});
```

Take a look at the configured dependency, `main` should wait for `common/lib` to load (which defines the `angular` module).

Here is my `main.js`:

```
define('main', ['angular'], function (angular)
{
    // Use angular here
});
```

The `main` module requires the `angular` module, but the `angular` module is in the `common/lib` bundle, so I'm telling `main` to wait for `common/lib` so the module is defined.

However, this does not seem to work, `main` does not wait for `common/lib`, and therefore, tries to locate an undefined `angular` module with no luck, raising an error.

So, my question is:

***How can I configure dependencies for the main module?***

---

I should note that I'm not using `data-main` attribute on the `script` tag for `main.js`.

Instead, I'm loading it as a normal script after `config.js`, and I then execute this line to load the `main` module:

```
require(['main']);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is solved by using the [`bundles`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles) configuration option. You add this to your config:

```
bundles: {
  'common/lib': ['angular', ...]
}
```

This essentially tells RequireJS that when it wants to load the `angular` module it should load the `common/lib` module and then `angular` will be defined. I've put `...` in the list because you may want to add other module names there.

Note that `shim` is only meant for modules that are not proper AMD modules (i.e. those that do not call `define`). Using `shim` with modules that are AMD modules results in undefined behavior. So your use of `shim` in your question is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to remove the shim dependency and specify it as a module requirement at `main` definition:

```
define('main', ['common/lib'], function ()
{
     // 'angular' module is guaranteed to be defined
     var angular = require('angular');

     // Use angular here
});
```

As you can see I'm later loading the `angular` module using the `require()` function.